# Conceptual question on the force experienced by a plate on one of its sides

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, integration

I imagined a situation like this:

Let's say dip a plate in water so that it is just submerged.

I Tried to calculate the force experienced by the plate in one of its sides.

To do that I must find total pressure and multiply by area

As pressure increases deeper the plate is submerged we must integrate to find the total pressure on one of its sides

This is how it turned out .

$\int_0^H\rho g dh\times A$

Here A is the area of the plate

Which is $\rho ghA$

Is this correct? Something feels a bit off here

I am a beginner at physics so if this is a very simple question I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to consider a thin strip for writing its area
Let the length of small strip be l and small height as $dy$
$Force= (\rho)gy$ ____________$area=ldy$

$\int_0^H\rho g dh\times A$

$\int_0^H\rho g y\times ldy$

$ \rho$$gy^2/2$

Note# since we are measuring pressure from up assuming it increases as we go down the limits will be different upper limit will be less than lower limit since in final position is lower than initial

Comment: U can ask if any doubt

Comment: Thanks ! Sorry for the late acceptance totally forgot.